# rsync : Recursively sync all files while ignoring the directory structure

Tags: bash, rsync

I am trying to create a bash script for syncing music from my desktop to a mobile device. The desktop is the source.

Is there a way to make rsync recursively sync files but ignore the directory structure? If a file was deleted from the desktop, I want it to be deleted on the device as well.

The directory structure on my desktop is something like this.

```
    Artist1/
        Artist1/art1_track1.mp3
        Artist1/art1_track2.mp3
        Artist1/art1_track3.mp3
    Artist2/
        Artist2/art2_track1.mp3
        Artist2/art2_track2.mp3
        Artist2/art2_track3.mp3
    ...
```

The directory structure that I want on the device is:

```
    Music/
        art1_track1.mp3
        art1_track2.mp3
        art1_track3.mp3
        art2_track1.mp3
        art2_track2.mp3
        art2_track3.mp3
    ...
```

Comment: One thing you have not mentioned is wether you want the files removed from your device to be also removed from your desktop. This does change a lot of things.

Comment: No, I don't want any changes in the device to be reflected on the desktop. I just want the device to be in sync with the source.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Update: nov 2023

### 1. Without `find`, by using `bash`'s *globstar*

Simply:

```
rsync -a --delete --include=*.mp3 --exclude=* \
    pathToSongs/Theme*/Artist*/. destuser@desthost:Music/.
```

would do the job if you're path hierarchy has a fixed number of level.

WARNING: if two song file do have exactly same name, while on same destination directory, your backup will miss one of them!

If else, and for answering strictly to your ask *ignoring the directory structure* you could use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s `shopt -s globstar` feature:

```
shopt -s globstar
rsync -a --delete --include=*.mp3 --exclude=* \
    pathToSongsRoot/**/. destuser@desthost:Music/.
```

At all, there is no need to fork to `find` command.

#### 1.1 Recursively sync all files while ignoring the directory structure

For answering strictly to question, there must no be limited to an extension:

```
shopt -s globstar
rsync -d --delete sourceRoot/**/. destuser@desthost:destRoot/.
```

With this, directories will be copied too, but without content. All files **and** directories would be stored on same level at `destRoot/`.

WARNING: If some different files with same name exists in defferents directories, they would simply be overwrited on destination, durring rsync, for finaly storing randomly only one.

### 2. By using `find`

When you use `find`, you may have to ensure *special character* in filenames to be correctly handled. For this you should use `-print0` option to separate filenames by *null* chars (`0x0`), then tell `rsync` to read *stdin* by using *null* chars as separator:

```
find first/source/path second/source/path -type f -name \*.mp3 -print0 |
    rsync -av0 --files-from - --no-relative . destuser@desthost:destRoot/.
```

(Note the little `0` after `-av`, mean `-a -v -0`.)

This syntax is based on ***relative path***! If you plan to use ***full path*** you will use full path as `find` arguments and replace dot (*current path*) by a slash (*root*) in `rsync` command:

```
find /first/source/path /second/source/path -type f -name \*.mp3 -print0 |
    rsync -av0 --files-from - --no-relative / destuser@desthost:destRoot/.
```

Comment: You ignored the condition that files that are no longer in the source tree should be deleted....

Comment: Yup, @holgero is right this will not delete files that have been deleted in the source tree.

Comment: Yep, you are right, this version works. (You need to have a given file extension, but as the question was specifically about music data, that may be a valid assumption.)

Comment: @holgero No, this command work even without `--include=*.mp3 --exclude=*` options (but with `-d` instead of `-a`!!).

Comment: This is great. I can confirm that this works. I haven't checked the speedup yet. @holgero I am syncing locally, does the speedup comment from below still hold?

Comment: @F.Hauri, could you please explain what `sourceRoot/**/.` means?

Comment: @SrinathSridhar Something like *recursively dirs only*... Sorry, It's a sunny sunday now, my childrens are waiting for me... Take a look at bash's man page: `man -Len -Pless\ +/globstar bash`

Comment: @SrinathSridhar You could use rsync *remotely* on `localhost`, for testing purpose, ( if you have ssh installed localy ).

Answer (score 18):

May be this is a recent option, but I see the option `--no-relative` mentioned in the documentation for `--files-from` and it worked great.

```
find SourceDir -name \*.mp3 | rsync -av --files-from - --no-relative . DestinationDir/
```

Comment: As of 2022 this is the correct answer

Comment: Instead of `.` you need to use `/` if your source dir is an absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question: No, `rsync` cannot do this alone. But with some help of other tools, we can get there... After a few tries I came up with this:

```
rsync -d --delete $(find . -type d|while read d ; do echo $d/ ; done) /targetDirectory && rmdir /targetDirectory/* 2>&-
```

The difficulty is this: To enable deletion of files at the target position, you need to:

1. specify directories as sources for rsync (it doesn't delete if the source is a list of files).
2. give it the complete list of sources at once (`rsync` within a loop will give you the contents of the last directory only at the target).
3. end the directory names with a slash (otherwise it creates the directories at the target directory)

So the command substitution (the stuff enclosed with the `$(` `)`) does this: It finds all directories and adds a slash (/) at the end of the directory names. Now rsync sees a list of source directories, all terminated with a slash and so copies their contents to the target directory. The option `-d` tells it, not to copy recursively.

The second trick is the `rmdir /targetDirectory/*` which removes the empty directories which `rsync` created (although we didn't ask it to do that).

I tested that here, and deletion of files removed in the source tree worked just fine.

Comment: I just tried this but it seems that every run of rsync "re-copies" existing files. The speedup on completion is 1.00 even on same bunch of source files.

Comment: @doukremt would you please care to elaborate, why my answer is crappy? That would give me a chance to improve it.

Comment: @SrinathSridhar tried it here with "rsync  version 3.0.9  protocol version 30" and my results were: First sending: "sent 82828146 bytes  received 14497 bytes  15062298.73 bytes/sec
total size is 141608421  speedup is 1.71

real    0m5.066s
user    0m1.630s
sys     0m0.308s"
Second attempt:
"sent 221741 bytes  received 246582 bytes  104071.78 bytes/sec
total size is 141608579  speedup is 302.37

real    0m3.884s
user    0m0.472s
sys     0m0.041s". So I get a factor of 300 as speedup.

Comment: But rsync shows a speedup only if the target is on another host. Seems it won't optimize local transfers.

Comment: I had issues with the remove part of your script. I use: 'find . -type d -empty -delete' instead. of && rmdir /targetDirectory/* 2>&-

Answer (score 1):

If you can make a list of files, you've already solved the problem.
Try:

```
find /path/to/src/ -name \*.mp3 > list.txt
rsync -avi --no-relative --progress --files-from=list.txt / user@server:/path/to/dest
```

If you run the script again for new files, it will only copy the missing files.

If you don't like the list, then try a single sentence (but it's another logic)

```
find /path/to/src/ -name \*.mp3 -type f \
  -exec rsync -avi --progress {} user@server:/path/to/dest/  \;
```

In this case, you will ask for each file, each time, since by the type of sentence, you cannot build the file list previously.