# Rsync make flat copy

Tags: linux, file, copy, rsync, flat

I'm trying to write a script that copy all the files of one dir (with subdirs) to the root of another dir.

So Imagine I have this file structure:

```
/
pic.JPG
PIC5.JPG
FOLDER
  pic2.JPG
  pic3.JPG
  FOLDER2
    pic4.JPG
```

I want all the .JPG files from that directory and copy them over to another destination. But I don't want the directory structure, just the files.

This is what I've got:

```
"sudo rsync -aq  --include '*/' --include '*.JPG' --exclude '*\' /source/picturesRoot/ /destination/flatView/
```

But it also copies the directories :(
I found this link on stackoverflow:
[rsync : Recursively sync all files while ignoring the directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661033/rsync-recursively-sync-all-files-while-ignoring-the-directory-structure)

I looked at the solution and didn't see much difference with my command, apart from the * and . in the path. I tried it but it didn't work.

I hope somebody can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer cannot work for you because your pictures are not at the same level in directories. There is no option in `rsync` to skip the creation of directory structure. In the link you gave, it's working because the user explicitly select source files with `*`.

You can try something with `find` and `rsync`. `Find` will find files and `rsync` copy them.

Here is a solution :

```
find /source/picturesRoot -type f -name "*.JPG" -exec rsync -a {} /destination/flatView/ \;
```

Be careful, if two files have the same name just one will be in destination directory.

Comment: hmmm will have a look.

Comment: @user2815780 I added a solution with find and rsync. I have tried, it's working.

Comment: thank you very much, will try it. and I'm pretty sure there won't be two files with the same name.

Comment: For a more efficient solution (only 1 invocation of rsync) see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661033/rsync-recursively-sync-all-files-while-ignoring-the-directory-structure#14663054)

Comment: Referenced in comment "more efficient" solution requires Bash 4.0 or newer.