# rsync: Sync all files to single directory, ignoring directory structure

Tags: linux, unix, centos, synchronization, rsync

I would like to sync all **files** to a certain directory without syncing the directory structure.

So far, I have this:

```
rsync -vcr --remove-source-files --exclude='*sample*' --exclude='*Sample*' --include='*/' --include='*.avi' --include='*.mkv' --include='*.mp4' --include='*.wmv' --exclude='*' $src1 $src2 $dest
```

That seems to be working fairly well, but if one of the included file types are in a sub-directory of the source directories, the parent directories will also be transferred.

To sum it up, I want all included file types to be moved straight to the single destination directory, WITHOUT copying the parent directory structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rsync make flat copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24613009/rsync-make-flat-copy)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an extra `--include='*/` in your command that is not needed, and causing the issue you experience. You should go for the below:

### Edit

Let's also remove the `--exclude='*'` which might be redundant since we use `include` for the relevant files.

```
rsync -vcr --remove-source-files --exclude='*sample*' --exclude='*Sample*'        \
      --include='*.avi' --include='*.mkv' --include='*.mp4' --include='*.wmv'     \
      $src1 $src2 $dest
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried without the `--include='*/' `, and oddly enough it doesn't seem to be searching recursively (even with -r).

Comment: Let's also remove the `--exclude='*'` which might be redundant since we use `include` for the relevant files.